# Why doesn't the sperm die if there is citric acid and acid phosphatases in the semen?

Tags: reproductive-biology

While studying I read that sperm needs alkaline medium for its survival.But when I studied the composition of semen it revealed that semen contains citric acid which acts as a sperm nutrient along with fructose.It also contain acid phosphatases.So in such sitution how can the sperm survive?

Comment: Can you provide some sources?

Comment: From TextBook of Medical Physiology By Guyton and Hall.

Answer (score 2):

Citric acid is a [weak acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_acid#Weak_acids) so in the context of a buffered physiological medium (semen pH 7.7) it will not cause any significant acidification. Acid phosphatases are enzymes with a pH optimum below 7 (as distinct from alkaline pho sphatases). Their presence has no implications for the pH of semen, although it is interesting to speculate why an alkaline fluid would contain an acid phosphatase.

Comment: Vaginal pH is ~4. The acid phosphatases likely have some function in this environment.